# Why do a lot of languages lack a logical XOR operator?

Tags: language-design, bit-manipulation

Off the top of my head, I cannot think of a single language I've used that had a logical exclusive or operator, but all have logical and bitwise `and` and `or` operators.

Looking around, the only reason to this that I could find was that exclusive or cannot be short circuited, so a logical version would be useless, which I really can't see being the case. The reason it came to my attention that most languages lack this is that I needed it (I was using Ruby, so I wrote a method to convert an integer to a boolean, and then use bitwise XOR, which on booleans acts like logical XOR).

Just using bitwise XOR does not work either, because it will give a different result.

```
0b0001  ^  0b1000 = 0b1001 (True)
0b0001 XOR 0b1000 = False
// Where ^ is bitwise exclusive or and XOR is logical exclusive or
// Using != (not equal to) also doesn't work
0b0001 != 0b1000 = True
```

So why is it that most languages do not include a logical exclusive or operator?

*Edit*: I added an example with how `!=` also does not do what I want, it almost does, but falls into the *same* problem that using bitwise exclusive or does, it only works if you know that you are working with zero or one, and not any other number.

And to note, this is assuming that language uses zero as false and nonzero as true.

Comment: In your second example, it assumes a language which uses non-zero for true.

Comment: Can you give an example of how your logical XOR differs from not equal?

Comment: The *real* here is "Why are you trying to use Logical Operators on non-boolean values?"  That's semantically invalid and poor programming practice to begin with.

Comment: What RBarryYoung said.  You've got a bitwise XOR operator (^) to use with anything used as a bitmap.  You've got a logical XOR operator (!=) to use with boolean values.  You've got ways of creating boolean values from other types.  What more do you need?

Comment: So is it bad practice to use || or && on non boolean values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so you're looking for a *byte*wise exclusive-or versus a *bit*wise exclusive-or.  It seems like you're looking for something that will operate on a byte as "on" or "off", as thought the bytes are "0" or "nonzero", then XOR them.  It really sounds like you're looking to compress each byte into a single bit indicating true or false.  So, it sounds like you want (a!=0)^(b!=0)

```
 a  b    a YOURXOR b    a!=0   b!=0   (a!=0)^(b!=0)
 0  0         0          0       0        0        
 0  1         1          0       1        1
 1  0         1          1       0        1
 7  0         1          1       0        1
 0  7         1          0       1        1
 3  7         0          1       1        0
 7  3         0          1       1        0
 7  7         0          1       1        0
```

As for why that's not in every language... that I can't really answer.  However it's not all that difficult to implement with the building blocks of bitwise xor available in every language, and no language offers all possible functionality - they just offer enough to let you build the extended functionality you might need.  Oh, and if this were a popular enough problem, you'd expect to see libraries or macros all over the place for it; while I may not have made a sufficient search for such libs/code, I didn't find any myself, indicating that the requirement is either trivial to write, or a niche requirement.

Comment: I think !a^!b works too. In particular it works in Ruby as `!x` is a bool

Answer (score 22):

Nearly every language has a logical XOR. The symbol they use for it varies, but regardless of the symbol, most people pronounce it "not equal".

Edit: for those who doubt, test code for three variables:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            for (int k=0; k<2; k++) {
                std::cout << "\n!=" << (i!=j!=k);
                std::cout << "\t^ " << (i^j^k);
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can't guarantee a boolean context, that is asking for subtle bugs.

Comment: most languages have a bitwise XOR, but not a **logical** one.  "not equal" works the same in the case of tow operands, but I don't think a!=b!=c is equivalent to a XOR b XOR c.

Comment: And the inverse operation is *equivalence*, or simply *equals*.

Comment: @Craig McQueen:the only possible room for disagreement is about whether the bugs will (necessarily) be subtle!

Comment: @MadCoder, `!=` is a XOR when both operands are boolean. And yes, `a != b != c` is exactly equivalent to `a XOR b XOR c` if all operands are boolean.

Comment: Yep, I'm wrong.  Still, having an explicit XOR operator could address Craig's concerns as the operands could be cast to booleans automatically.

Comment: @MadCoder:There are undoubtedly circumstances under which it would be handy. OTOH, I can think of a lot of other operators I'm pretty sure I'd use a lot more often.

Comment: Added an example of how `!=` isn't a replacement for logical XOR. Oddly, it's the same example as before, except I put `!=` in there.

Comment: @Jeffrey:Yes, it's a *Boolean* XOR, so you have to ensure that the values are Boolean before you apply it to them. Since reversing them doesn't matter, you can use `!a != !b`;

Answer (score 8):

What do you mean by "logical XOR operator"? I'm not sure what result do you expect from your examples, but here's my answer:

`a (logical XOR) b` is the same as `bool(a) != bool(b)`

Inequality is a logical XOR. Since you already have the bitwise XOR version, you don't need a special operator for the logical one.

Answer (score 8):

You can also write `!a ^ !b` to get the same effect as a logical xor.

You probably don't find logical xor in programming languages because:

- it doesn't generate very efficient assembly code
- is not needed very often
- language designers have to put the line somewhere, why not NAND, NOR, NXOR, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I can think of is that the operation is relatively rare. I don't see why something like ^^ couldn't be assigned to it though, maybe people who design languages want to avoid operator clutter.

As to it being useless because it can't be short-circuited, in many strongly typed languages you can't use the bitwise XOR operator to compare booleans without casting back and forth, in which case even a non-short circuiting logical XOR would make sense to have.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because XOR isn't commonly needed as a logical operator, and you can do it almost as easily as this:

```
// foo xor bar
(foo & !bar) || (bar & !foo)

// or like this (assuming foo and bar are booleans)
!(foo==bar)

// assume boleans that can be cast as integers with true=1 and false=0
// foo XOR bar XOR baz XOR alice
((int)foo + (int)bar + (int)baz + (int)alice)&0b1
```

Comment: That will get complicated for three or four tests though.

Comment: Yep, but it's just one of those things that's rare enough for language designers to not care about.